# How to query 2 tables based on 2 columns?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following 2 tables and their relevant columns:

```
M
==
id: PRIMARY KEY
month1: TEXT (encoded month,year combination)
month2: TEXT
```

and

```
F
==
id: PRIMARY KEY
mid: NOT NULL REFERENCES M("id")
month: TEXT
```

There can 0..N rows in F for each row in M.

How do I select all the F rows such that the row's month is 1 of the 2months in the related M row, ie: the one where:

```
F.mid=M.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
F LEFT OUTER JOIN M ON F.mid = M.ID
WHERE (F.month = M.month1 OR F.month = M.month2)
```

I am not 100% what you are asking for but this joins the two tables on M.ID but also makes sure that the F.month is equal to either month1 or month2 of the related M row?